# How to find whole path to a file on computer using python

Tags: python

I am struggling a little bit with a task in python. I want to find path to a secific file using only `glob` and `re` module. Is it possible to find whole path to specific file in my computer using only `glob` module? Any hints strongly appreciated!

Comment: why you want to use only `glob` module? advised above built-in `os` module cope fine with your issue

Comment: yes ... im allowed to use only glob module ...

Comment: I think your search for the answer would be aided by knowing that you're trying to convert a "relative path" to an "absolute path".

Comment: Do you know the *relative* path of the file? Or are you *searching* for a file with a given name or pattern?

Comment: yes exactly ... im searching for a file with given name ...

Answer (score 0):

That's depend on wheter the file is findable using a glob. For example you can't search recursively for any file called `hello.txt`, but you can search for a file called `bar.txt` in a subdirectory of `foo` using `foo/*/bar.txt`. If you have a glob for the file (including path) you could use it directly.

If you want to search recursively one way is to (badly) emulate `os.walk` (which is clumpsy because it's more elegant to use `os.walk` directly). You list files and directories in a directory by using `glob("{0}/*".format(path))` (returns empty list if `path` is not a directory), then you just do that recursively and can then use `re` to filter out the results you want:

```
def stupidly_list_files(path=""):
    for p in glob("{0}*".format(path)):
         yield p
         for x in stupidly_list_files("{0}/".format(p)):
              yield x

def stupidly_match_files(regex):
    for p in stupidly_list_files():
         if regex.match(p):
              yield p
```

Note neither `glob` nor `re` modules know anything about the current working directory, so if you're looking for absulute path you're out of luck unless you know the absolute path where you want to root your search.